# 'TypeError: this is undefined' occurs when using members of a class from a functional component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, components, jsx

I am trying to pass data to a ReactJS component using NodeJS by making a simple NodeJS API hosted in a separate localhost (:9000). But I'm getting an error.

> TypeError: this is undefined

My belief is that this error occurred due to using 'this' inside the functional component. But I cannot find a way to resolve this problem.

The code which has the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class News extends React.Component{


   constructor (props){
      super(props);
      this.state={apiResponse:""};

   }

   callAPI(){
      fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
      .then(res => res.text ())
      .then(res => this.setState({apiResponse: res}));
      
      
   }

   componentWillMount(){
      this.callAPI();
   }
}

function Newsexport() {
 return (
    <div class="container1">
       <h1>IT WORKS YO!</h1>
      <p>{this.state.apiResponse}</p> 
    </div>
  )
};

export default Newsexport;
```

The code of the simple API hosted with NodeJS (/api/routes/testAPI.js)

```
var express = require("express");
var router=express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req,res,next){
    res.send("API is working");

});

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Make `callAPI` an arrow function or bind it in the constructor

Comment: I changed `callAPI(){` to `callAPI=() => {`. But Still the error appears. And also, I tried adding `this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this);` to the constructor(props). Unfortunately the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this` in a functional component which is wrong. Also you are setting state in one component and expecting the value in another component. Instead combine the two components like below -

```
 class News extends React.Component{

    constructor (props){
      super(props);
      this.state={apiResponse:""};
    }

    callAPI = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
        .then(res => res.text ())
        .then(res => this.setState({apiResponse: res}));
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      this.callAPI();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div class="container1">
          <h1>IT WORKS YO!</h1>
          <p>{this.state.apiResponse}</p> 
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  export default News;
```

**Let me know if this helps**.

Comment: @Jai kindly check the Newsexport functional component,  ‘this.state.apiresponse’ is used where he would get ‘this’ as ‘undefined’